# Rewrite java code into C# for making a payment using stripe gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stripe-payments

I have this java code and I want to make C# code that does the same thing.

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_2uoGykz3oyw8GNHWiBVEQY7N";
Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 400);
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", "tok_160DSpIZJBCsfX4YCKJKjg2O"); // obtained with Stripe.js
chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for test@example.com");
Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

Comment: You have failed to show why this code doesnt work.  Please elaborate on the errors you are receiving.

Comment: @paqogomez, I think that's Java code the OP has given us. I think he's asking someone to rewrite it in C# for him.

Comment: We all have jobs here, with our own work to do. We certainly have better things to do than sit porting java code to C# for people who can't be bothered to make the effort themselves.

Comment: I know c# and Java Also. But Issue is that In C Sharp "Stripe.apiKey" Key word not support. and I am using stripe.net as references in our application. I don't want to convert code. i need the help how to get "Stripe.apiKey" in charp code only.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe Payment using (C#) WCF Rest Service. This Code is correct to make payment to stripe gateway. You don't need any stripe dll. This will help to make payment.

```
PrivateKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"].ToString();
                StringBuilder postUrl = new StringBuilder();
                postUrl.Append("&card=");
                postUrl.Append(paymentDetail.Token);
                postUrl.Append("&currency=USD");
                postUrl.Append("&amount=");
                postUrl.Append(paymentDetail.Amount);                
                byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(postUrl.ToString());
                //Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
                var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges");
                webrequest.Method = "POST";
                webrequest.UserAgent = "Stripe Payment";
                webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                webrequest.Headers.Add("Stripe-Version", "2015-04-07");
                webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Concat("Basic ", (Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:", this.PrivateKey))))));

                using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
                }

                //Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream

                StreamReader reader = null;
                string stripeResponse;
                try
                {
                    var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
                    Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
                    reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                    stripeResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (WebException exception)
                {
                    using (WebResponse response = exception.Response)
                    {
                        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (reader = new StreamReader(data))
                        {
                            stripeResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();                                 
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

C# and Java have similar syntaxes, in fact the only change you would need to make to the code you posted is change the `HashMap<String, Object>` in to a `Dictionary<String, Object>`

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_2uoGykz3oyw8GNHWiBVEQY7N";
Dictionary<String, Object> chargeParams = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
chargeParams.Add("amount", 400);
chargeParams.Add("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.Add("source", "tok_160DSpIZJBCsfX4YCKJKjg2O"); // obtained with Stripe.js
chargeParams.Add("description", "Charge for test@example.com");
Charge.Create(chargeParams);
```

Comment: Stripe.apiKey  and Charge.create(); is not coming in c sharp and I am using stripe.net reference. Please let me know why stripe.apiKey keyword is not coming.

Comment: I have never used stripe.net, you need to look at their documentation to see what you need to do. However one thing that may be catching you is `Stripe` is likely a variable of a type derived from [`StripeService`](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/blob/master/src/Stripe/Services/StripeService.cs) and `apikey` would be a property on a class . Looking at the API briefly your code would likely change to `Stripe.ApiKey = "...`. C# uses capitals for their first letters of their public properties and methods.